# Publishing a jar to MVN central

Tags: jar, sonatype, mvn-repo

I'm trying to publish my [JAR](https://github.com/sap9433/dependencyInjection) to maven Central I followed every step given [here](https://central.sonatype.org/pages/gradle.html). The last step mentioned there is

```
gradle uploadArchives
```

Which worked, and said successfully uploaded. but when I go to [release site](https://oss.sonatype.org/#stagingRepositories), I don't see my jar there to release. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: File an issue at https://issues.sonatype.org in the "community support - open source hosting" project to get help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gradle uploadArchives` is successful doesn't always mean your artifact will be available for release (Sonatype calls them staging repository).

For my case my Artifact version was `1.0.0-Snapshot`. as I had `SnapShot` keyword in my version number it was actually released to SnapShot [repository](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/sap9433/dependency-inject/) . When I removed `snapshot` word from my version and redeployed it was available in [staging](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/staging/com/github/sap9433/dependency-inject/1.0/) and i was able to release it to mvn central

#### Steps for publishing -

- Create an [account](https://issues.sonatype.org/secure/Signup!default.jspa)
- Create a new Sonatype Open Source Project Repository Hosting [OSSRH](https://issues.sonatype.org/secure/CreateIssue.jspa)
- Your Project will be created . Wait for the ticket to [resolve](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/OSSRH-50941)
- Create a [gpg key](https://central.sonatype.org/pages/working-with-pgp-signatures.html) . (brew install gpg2 , gpg --gen-key, gpg --list-keys, gpg --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --send-keys CCB2F39ADC112552658A3EA60A1189B4C4B4D83B)
- Follow [this](https://central.sonatype.org/pages/gradle.html) to generate build.gradle.
- create gradle.properties in your root and add to .gitignore.[Add secret](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/signing_plugin.html)

```
signing.keyId=C4B4D83B  #(gpg --list-keys , last 8 digit )
signing.password=z_*** #(password that you used to sign keys)
signing.secretKeyRingFile=/Users/<ur machine username>/.gnupg/secring.gpg
ossrhUsername=sapy
ossrhPassword=<ossrhpassword from google key chain>
```

- to upload your changes to sonatype release manager - `gradle uploadArchives`
- Dont forget to remove snapshot from version ,
- Now go to (https://oss.sonatype.org/#stagingRepositories) , select your repository , check, and click on `close`. It takes some time to close.
- Once you have successfully closed the staging repository, you can release it by pressing the `Release` button. This will move the components into the release repository of OSSRH where it will be synced to the Central Repository.
- If some of the guideline fails you will see the steps that failed in Red. and 'Release' button will not be activated. Drop it and re upload and reclose.
- Last 3 steps are well documented [here](https://central.sonatype.org/pages/gradle.html) and [here](https://central.sonatype.org/pages/releasing-the-deployment.html)
- After 10 minutes to 2hrs . Your changes will reflect [search.maven.org](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.sap9433/dependency-inject/1.0/jar).
- changes should be available immediately after release in [release site](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/staging/com/github/sap9433/dependency-inject/)